# Add custom country name with different international dial code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input to get flag and international county code.

```
 var phonePrefix = $("#phonePrefix");
 phonePrefix.intlTelInput({
      preferredCountries: preferredCountries,
      onlyCountries: onlyCountries,
    });

  phonePrefix.on('keydown', function (e) {
    //dont allow to input other characters apart from numbers and + sign
    if (!isAllowedChar(e)) return false;
    //dont allow to remove + sign that appears as first character
    if (($(this).get(0).selectionStart == 0 && (e.keyCode < 35 || e.keyCode > 40))

      || ($(this).get(0).selectionStart == 1 && e.keyCode == 8)) {
      return false;
    }
  })

/**
   * Allows only to input numbers or the plus sign
   */
  function isAllowedChar(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    //allow plus sign
    if (charCode === 43) return true;

    //allow nav buttons
    if (charCode >= 35 && charCode <= 40) return true;

    //allow digits
    if (charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) return true;

    //allow backspace
    if (charCode === 8) return true;

    //allow delete
    if (charCode === 46) return true;


    return false;
  }
```

And I have flag with international country code. Now I need to add some more international code for some specific country.

If I try add array in var allCountries like

```
[ "Mexico (México)", "mx", "521" ]
```

in intlTelInput.js and its works. But I don't want to edit plugin. Is it possible to add without touching plugin?

Thank You

Comment: You have https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input/blob/master/src/js/data.js and that is where you already have `[
    "Mexico (México)",
    "mx",
    "52"
  ],` - if you need to add one, look at the criteria and if your country conforms, do a pull request and edit data.js to include your country

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.But I want to add country 'Mexico' with another international code '521'.

Comment: I want add one more mexico with 3 digit.Thanks you

Comment: I know but my client demand. I try explain him too but he want this.

Comment: Then you need to edit data.js - which I do not see is a problem

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks